# Can't figure out Symfony Exception 'The name must not contain ".."'

Tags: php, symfony

I'm starting a new Symfony app and just set up some custom folders made my user entity and migrated the DB and my first controller but I'm getting this exception whenever I try to load a page. Any ideas what's going on?

```
InvalidArgumentException
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
The name must not contain ".."
```

Playing around with service definitions and i'll instead get a message saying it was looking for my controller class but couldn't find it even though I can use a PHPStorm shortcut from the service definition to the class and vice versa.

I would expect the template to load with `hello, world`

Comment: Can you identify, in your code, to which name this error message is referring? What purpose does that entity serve? The only thing I can think of is that it refers to an absolute path, and that it shouldn't contain ".." because that signifies a parent directory. Then again, you give very little information to go on.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing suggests that there is an issue with the name of one of your custom folders. It appears that the name of the folder may contain "..", which is not allowed in Symfony. Try renaming your custom folders without any special characters.

Concerning the message stating that your controller class could not be found, this could be due to a problem with your controller class's namespace or file path. Check that your controller class's namespace matches the directory structure of your custom folders, and that your controller class's file path fits the namespace. Also, ensure that the file name of your controller class corresponds to the class name (e.g., MyController.php should contain a MyController class).

If you are still having problems after reviewing these things, please offer more information about your directory structure, namespace, file locations, and any relevant code samples so that the problem can be diagnosed more correctly.